# my Querysnapshot Map String become AsyncSnapshot<Object> with no reason

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have a streamBuilder where the "snapshots()" change from  `Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`  to `AsyncSnapshot<Object?>`.
This is weird because I have another app, with identical code and works fine.
The problem is, I cannot access "snapshot.data.docs" and all firestore datas.
Why is happening?

my code:

```
 body: StreamBuilder(
             //Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
      stream: firestore.collection('Books').orderBy('name').snapshots(),

                 //AsyncSnapshot<Object?>
      builder:  (context, snapshot ) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        {
          final document = snapshot.data?; //error here
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: document?.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your StreamBuilder Widget response type as a dynamic, and you should use

snapshot.data.docs without any problem.

> ```
>  body: StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
>  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Books').orderBy('name').snapshots(),
>
>  builder: (context, snapshots) {
>       if(snapshots.hasData){
>          print(snapshots.data.docs.toString());
>       }});
> ```

Comment: Nice thanks a lot. Why it's happening now, while not before? maybe because ùI just update to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1?

Comment: A stream can be anything, not just a listener called to get data, so you can expect all types of responses, not just the firestore one, so when you tell the widget that the response can be anything (by using dynamic) then you have a bigger room to control the response shape commensurate with your stream type.